# undefined reference to symbol 'boost::future_category()'

Tags: linux, cassandra

I have installed boost along with other dependencies needed for [Cassandra cpp driver](https://github.com/datastax/cpp-driver/blob/master/README.md) on my ubuntu 12.04 LTS. When I try to run command below it ends up with two errors. I have looked for solutions but can't find any. Some say to link in the libboost_system by adding the option -lboost_system which I tried, but doesn't help.

Here is the cmd: cmake . && make && make cql_demo && make cql_test && make test && make install -lboost_system

All i want to do is to run the demo from the driver and to communicate with the cassandra database!

Errors:

```
-- info CMAKE_BINARY_DIR: /home/pi/experiments/cpp-driver-master2
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/pi/experiments/cpp-driver-master2
[ 42%] Built target cql
[ 85%] Built target cql_static
[ 87%] Built target CCMBridge
Linking CXX executable cql_integration_tests
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libboost_thread.so.1.55.0, needed by /usr/local/lib/libboost_log.so, may conflict with libboost_thread.so.1.46.1
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/cql_integration_tests.dir/src/test_utils.cpp.o: undefined reference to symbol 'boost::future_category()'
/usr/bin/ld: note: 'boost::future_category()' is defined in DSO /usr/local/lib/libboost_thread.so.1.55.0 so try adding it to the linker command line
/usr/local/lib/libboost_thread.so.1.55.0: could not read symbols: Invalid operation
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [test/integration_tests/cql_integration_tests] Error 1
make[1]: *** [test/integration_tests/CMakeFiles/cql_integration_tests.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libboost_thread.so.1.55.0, needed by /usr/local/lib/libboost_log.so, may conflict with libboost_thread.so.1.46.1
```

is basically saying that you have two versions of Boost installed:

- Custom built one in `/usr/local/lib/`, probably version 1.55.0.
- Another one in system directories, probably version 1.46.1.

and when they both get linked to your binary version 1.46.1 wins.

You need to see all complete command lines that CMake invokes for you to tell exactly where the problem is.